# Could there be massive gravitons and in our spacetime?

Tags: particle-physics, gravity, energy, mass

My question is: Could there in principle be sub-groups of gravitons (if they existed) that has mass (and in our spacetime dimensions) such as those affected by electric or by strong force or other forces which could be above the energy threshold of our current particle accelerators. (Perhaps they could be created, say, near pulsars due to high-energy collisions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a speculative question and can only have the answer that mathematically it is conceivable that the theory of everything ( TOE) may contain higher mass gravitons.

After all in the [electroweak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction) interactions the photon, the Z and the W are all to start with zero mass carriers of the electroweak force, and then symmetry breaking makes the photon massless and the Z and W ( weak force carriers) massive.

So their might be higher mass graviton-like particles  in some theories .